# Update text on textarea value change w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea. I need to update text in a div when a value in textarea is changed by either **typing** in it or by **placing some value in it via another jQuery function** or **pasted**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function myFunc() {
        var input = $("#myTxt").val();
        $("#txtHere").text(input);
    }       
    myFunc();

    // EDIT BELOW -- this will update while typing
    $("#myTxt").keyup(myFunc);

});

<textarea id="myTxt"></textarea>
<div id="txtHere"></div>
```

It loads the value on page load but I'm not sure what to use to check for value in the textarea...

Comment: Please don't edit the question to add the answer, this makes it confusing to know what is really the thing that was asked.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function myFunc(){
        var input = $("#myTxt").val();
        $("#txtHere").text(input);
    }       
    myFunc();

    //either this
    $('#myTxt').keyup(function(){
        $('#txtHere').html($(this).val());
    });

    //or this
    $('#myTxt').keyup(function(){
        myFunc();
    });

    //and this for good measure
    $('#myTxt').change(function(){
        myFunc(); //or direct assignment $('#txtHere').html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: I think the last option is a good addition to update while typing. Can't I just do: $('#myTxt').keyUp(myFunc); ?

Comment: "for good measure" sounds like you aren't really sure what's going to be executed

Answer (score 14):

For textarea, the .change function only gets called when the textarea looses focus.

I found my solution at this link: [How can I bind to the change event of a textarea in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338592/jquery-textarea-change-event)

```
$('#textareaID').bind('input propertychange', function() {
      $("#yourBtnID").hide();

      if(this.value.length){
        $("#yourBtnID").show();
      }
});
```

This worked perfectly for me. It handles any type of change, including pasting.

Plus `this.value.length` is a neat way of seeing if the textarea has been cleared.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please summarise the link in your answer; that way, if the link goes stale the answer won't be completely useless.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myTxt').keypress(function(e){
       $('#txthere').html($(this).val());
   });
});
```

This will do that.

Comment: Only if he pastes text via shortcut. Using context menu will not trigger this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `delegate` event like this:

```
$('body').delegate('#myTxt', 'keyup change', function(){
   $('#txtHere').text(this.value);
});
```

This should update the text as soon as you type in the text box or paste.

Comment: I have another function where a value can be posted in this textarea by selecting from a list. But thinking of it, it's a textarea, pasting in is a possibility...

Answer (score 1):

### 2018, without JQUERY

*The question is **with** JQuery, it's just FYI.*

#### JS

```
let myTxt = document.getElementById('myTxt');
let txtHere = document.getElementById('txtHere');
myTxt.addEventListener('input', function() {
    txtHere.innerHTML = myTxt.value;
});
```

#### HTML

```
<textarea id="myTxt"></textarea>
<div id="txtHere"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the change event handler (will activate when the content is changed and the textarea loses focus):

```
$('#myTxt').change(function(){
    var input = $("#myTxt").val();
    $("#txtHere").text(input );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).delegate('#myTextareaId','input', function() {
  $('#myTextId').html($(this).val());
});
```